change column color depending on value WPFToolkit Chart Control
I have the WPFToolKit-Chart control which contains date and hours worked values. I want to change the color of column according to values. For example, I want to make the color orange when it exceeds working hours like the picture below.
I created grid control into the template property.
I divided this in two. But I couldn't find out how to adjust the grid heights.

This is my XAML markup:
    xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    
        <chartingToolkit:Chart Name="chart1"
                               Title="Availability"
                               VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
       
        <chartingToolkit:Chart.Series>
                    <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries  ItemsSource="{Binding MyGraph}"
                                       IndependentValuePath="Key"
                                       DependentValuePath="Value">
    
           <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
               <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:ColumnDataPoint">
                   <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                 <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:ColumnDataPoint">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                             <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                             <RowDefinition Height="200"/> <!--How can i adjust this height values-->    
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle Fill="Orange"
                                   Stroke="Black" />
                        <Rectangle Fill="Green"
                                   Grid.Row="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                   </ControlTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
             </Style>
            
           </chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
        </chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart.Series>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>

This is the view model:
private ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> myGraph;

public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> MyGraph
{
    get { return myGraph; }
    set 
    {
        myGraph = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
public ChartVM()
{
    MyGraph = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>()
    {
        new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int> (DateTime.Now, 8),
        new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int> (DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), 11),
        new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int> (DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), 7),
        new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int> (DateTime.Now.AddDays(3), 14),
        new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int> (DateTime.Now.AddDays(4), 5),
    };
}

This is result:

